# How can i set in Symfony bundles the configuration for API-Platform to load my resources.xml

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to use API Platform and Symfony to write a bundle for a software I use and I want to use an XML file to configure entity mapping.

I already know that somehow I have to work with the `routing.yml` but not like that.

I need to load following XML File:
[/src/VacationManager/Resources/config/api_platform/resources.xml](https://haste.scolasti.co/utike.xml)

And I tried to get it with following Files:
[/src/VacationManager/Resources/routing.yml](https://haste.scolasti.co/ekomu.yml)
[/src/VacationManager/Resources/config/api_platform.yaml](https://haste.scolasti.co/tenat.yaml)

Unfortunately Symfony does not seem to load the configuration file because I get the error `"404: No route found for 'GET / vacation'"`.

Comment: could you share app config and parameter (not only bundle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i needed was this:

```php
class DependencyInjection extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {}

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $apiPlatformConfig=[
            "mapping"=>[
                "paths"=> [
                    "%kernel.project_dir%/src/VacationManager/Resources/config/api_platform/"
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('api_platform', $apiPlatformConfig);
    }

}
```